# Is there any performance issue allocate ByteBuffer with one position?

Tags: java, performance, nio

I was wondering if there is any performance issue related to read just one byte from AsynchronousSocketChannel. I am implementing a simple HTTP server and parsing a request where I need read  byte per byte:

```
    ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(1);

    int end = 0;

    int br = 0;
    int bread = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    while(bread < RCV_BUF){

        br = client.read(dst).get();

        //End of stream and nothing :(
        if(br == 0){
            return null;
        }

        dst.flip();

        bread += br;

        byte b = dst.get();

        dst.clear();

        if((end == 0 && b == '\r') || (end == 1 && b == '\n') || (end == 2 && b == '\r')){
            end++;
        }
        else 
            if(end == 3 && b == '\n'){
                break;
            }
            else
            {
                end = 0;
            }

        sb.append((char)b);

    }
```

Can a Java expert explain me if that practice is bad or not in terms of performance?

Comment: In general, I would say the performance implication would be that you are creating an entire object to hold one byte.  I don't know why you would choose to use a ByteBuffer when you could just use a `byte` array of one.  If you are creating a lot of them, then your GC is going to go nuts trying to recover all the unused space.

Comment: I am creating an entire object to hold just one byte just because I don't have any other alternative to read bytes from the AsynchronousSocketChannel :( (well... as I know)! The read method requires a ByteBuffer! But i saw that ByteBuffer internally uses a byte array. If I create just one ByteBuffer object, this is not a problem right (the socket will use the same byte array from ByteBuffer)?

Comment: Could you possibly rethink your design to read in all available bytes at once instead of trying to go for 1 at a time?  Seems very inefficient.

Comment: Agreed - better rethink the design than trying to work around not having to do that. But if there is no way out given the time limitations / boundaries of skill and knowledge... I guess you could always make sure to use the same bytebuffer object and not let it be garbage collected, for example to create a 'scratch' bytebuffer for each unique thread. Blegh!

Comment: I know that isn't efficient, but how can I know how many bytes are available without read all SO_RCV_BUF (generally request don't use entire buffer)? I didn't find how to deal with this situation ! AsynchronousSocketChannel doesn't provide that information

Comment: `br = client.read(dst).get()` holds the number of bytes read; also `ByteBuffer.remaining` can be used.

Comment: In this case I have to allocate ByteBuffer with RCV_BUF (socket buffer limit) no? (remaining returns the number of elements between the current position and the limit of ByteBuffer) This is not efficient too because I may being allocating an array that I will not use entirely! Suppose request has just 300 bytes. If I allocate ByteBuffer with 20000 bytes,  19700 bytes will be too waste of space!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Normally you would try to read in as many bytes as possible into the buffer, all at once. This is significantly more efficient: ByteBuffers are highly optimised for reads and writes of big sequential chunks of bytes.

However, you can still make ByteBuffers work with a buffer size of one. If the volume of byte reads is smallish (say, 100,000 bytes per second or less) then I doubt it will make any noticeable difference. Your code looks fine for handling that sort of volume. As always, you should benchmark if you think it is a real concern, but there's little point optimising code if it is already fast enough for your needs.

But more seriously, I would question **why you are writing this kind of code at all**? Why not use a well tested library like (e.g. [Netty](http://netty.io/)) which should do all of this sort of stuff for you?

Comment: Well I could read, e.g., 256 bytes each time and accumulate... But this way I introduce complexity in the parser. Thanks for the response!  Well I like implement things by myself ahhaha I have more control about code and I like to know how stuffs work!

Comment: Normally you would read `min(bytes available, buffer size)` and accumulate until the full input is complete. That's a pretty common pattern in buffered IO code.

Comment: But how can I obtain the "available" bytes using AsynchronousSocketChannel?

Comment: Just use AsynchronousSocketChannel.read(...), these methods should read bytes up to the available amount.

Answer (score 0):

Well! I found a more efficient way to deal with this! I allocated ByteBuffer with a min size! The bad thing is that I introduced some complexity in the parser. But anyway...

```
    int RCV_BUF = client.getOption(StandardSocketOptions.SO_RCVBUF);

    ByteBuffer dst = ByteBuffer.allocate(256);

    int end = 0;

    int br = 0;
    int bread = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

    boolean endr = false;
    boolean cr = false;

    //Try parse headers
    while(!endr && bread < RCV_BUF){

        br = client.read(dst).get();

        //End of stream and nothing :(
        if(br == 0){
            return null;
        }

        dst.flip();

        bread += br;

        while(dst.hasRemaining()){

            byte b = dst.get();

            if(end == 0 && b == '\r'){      
                end++;
                continue;
            }

            // Possible header...
            if(end == 1){

                      // We got a header!
                if(b == '\n'){

                    // Reached the end of headers!
                    if(cr){
                        endr = true;
                        break;
                    }

                    cr = true;

                    end = 0;

                    System.out.println(sb.toString());

                    sb = new StringBuilder();

                    continue;
                }

                //Bad request (send a 400 status code...)!
                return null;
            }

            if(cr){
                cr = false;
            }

            sb.append((char)b);

        }

        dst.clear();

    }
```